# java plotting using for loop versus actionListener object

Tags: java, swing, graphics, actionlistener, bufferedimage

I was wondering why I couldn't use the same effect by using the for loop, versus using inner class with an actionlistener object to refresh plots of points on an image. Here are the codes:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class MyCanvas
{
    JLabel view;
    BufferedImage surface;
    Random random = new Random();
    public void initMyCanvas()
    {
        surface = new BufferedImage(1000,1000,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        view = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(surface));
        Graphics g = surface.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
        ActionListener listener=new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                int[] xLoc = new int[10]; 
                int[] yLoc = new int[10];
                System.out.println("drawing..");
                Graphics g = surface.getGraphics();
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);

                Random rn=new Random();

                for (int ji=0;ji<10;ji++){
                    xLoc[ji]=rn.nextInt(500);
                    yLoc[ji]=rn.nextInt(500);
                }

                drawNodes(xLoc,yLoc,g);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, listener);
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        canvas.initMyCanvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        int vertexes = 0;
        vertexes = 10;
        int canvasSize = vertexes * vertexes;
        frame.setSize(canvasSize, canvasSize);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(canvas.view);        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void drawNodes(int[] x, int[] y, Graphics g)
    {
            // Treat each location as a 10x10 block. If position 1,1 then go to (5,5) - If position 3,5 then go to (25, 45) eg: (x*10)-5, (y*10)-5
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            System.out.println(" In drawNodes");
            for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
                g.fillOval(x[i], y[i], 8, 8);
            }
            g.dispose();
            view.repaint();
    }
}
```

Versus the one implemented with the for loop to iterate over the same 'section' of the codes multiple times to create the plots.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class MyCanvas
{
    JLabel view;
    BufferedImage surface;
    Random random = new Random();
    public void initMyCanvas()
    {
        surface = new BufferedImage(1000,1000,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        view = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(surface));
        Graphics g = surface.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
        for (int i=0; i<5;i++){
            int[] xLoc = new int[10]; 
            int[] yLoc = new int[10];
            System.out.println("drawing..");

            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);

            Random rn=new Random();

            for (int ji=0;ji<10;ji++){
                xLoc[ji]=rn.nextInt(500);
                yLoc[ji]=rn.nextInt(500);
            }

            drawNodes(xLoc,yLoc,g);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        canvas.initMyCanvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        int vertexes = 0;
        vertexes = 10;
        int canvasSize = vertexes * vertexes;
        frame.setSize(canvasSize, canvasSize);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(canvas.view);        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void drawNodes(int[] x, int[] y, Graphics g)
    {
            // Treat each location as a 10x10 block. If position 1,1 then go to (5,5) - If position 3,5 then go to (25, 45) eg: (x*10)-5, (y*10)-5
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            System.out.println(" In drawNodes");
            for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
                g.fillOval(x[i], y[i], 8, 8);
            }
            g.dispose();
            view.repaint();
    }
}
```

The reason I ask is because I'm writing the equivalent implementation in Xtend, as a part of a Domain-specific language building effort; and I'm having problems being able to write inner classes and/or implement the ActionListener interface. And again, this would be a nice thing to de-mystify for myself as well !!

Answer (score 0):

Problem of method 2 is you call your loop in EDT, because of, it blocks and can't paint your components. Read [Swing Concurency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

1)Swing `Timer` is suitable for drawing with intervals. With timer you needn't to use `Thread.sleep(1);`.

2)You can try to use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for repainting. You can find a lot of examples for that.

3)Also use custom paintings in `paintComponent()` method watch next [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446768/2894369) and [read oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)