# Why is my code running the for loop more than 5 times?

Tags: java, for-loop

I sound really silly for asking this, but I'm having trouble with my for loop.

Here is part of the code I'm having trouble with.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
int number;
for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  System.out.print("Enter 5 integers:");
  number = input.nextInt();
}
```

When I run it the print out loops more than 5 times.

```
public class BarGraph extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
       // super.paintComponent(g);
        int number;

        for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        {
             System.out.print("Enter 5 integers:");
        number = input.nextInt();
       // g.drawRect(10 * i, 10 * i, 100 * number, 10);    
        }
    }
}
```

Running BarGraphTest

```
public class BarGraphTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        BarGraph panel = new BarGraph();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        application.add( panel );
        application.setSize( 300, 300);
        application.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is read 5 integers and just display them on JPanel line a bar graph.

Comment: The culprit is `input.nextInt();`. Use `input.nextLine();` instead.

Comment: How many more times than 5?

Comment: Print out the value of `i`

Comment: It should run only 5 times (or less if you don't type integer values as inputs). Are you sure about the code you posted?

Comment: @Tiny: `nextLine` produces a `String`. Need to parse the integer.

Comment: Show us the exact output you get.

Comment: That can be parsed to `int`, @staticx

Comment: If I run your code the loop is executed exactly 5 times.

Comment: @Tiny: `nextInt` will work fine in this example.. now if he had a bunch of them, that's a different story.. you can iterate over them and `nextLine` would be helpful.

Comment: Enter 5 integers:3
Enter 5 integers:4
Enter 5 integers:5
Enter 5 integers:6
Enter 5 integers:7
Enter 5 integers:8
Enter 5 integers:2
Enter 5 integers:1
Enter 5 integers:2
Enter 5 integers:4

Comment: @user3485650 Could we see an entire class that replicates this, something strange is going on

Comment: @user3485650 Print out the value of `i` in each iteration. That might give you a better clue as to what's going on. As Richard said more code would be useful - it may be that this block of code is, itself getting repeatedly executed.

Comment: I note that it produces exactly 10 outputs which would support a theory that this piece of code is being called twice

Comment: paintComponent is called by swing ["when it needs to be"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15545309/2187042), in this case it seems it needs 2 repaints. I personally would not mix up graphics and logic like this for exactly this kind of reason

Answer (score 4):

You have mixed up state change with graphics. `paintComponent` is called by swing ["when it needs to be"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545309/2187042), in this case Swing determined it needed 2 repaints, for whatever reason.

If your program is written in a way that it cares when or how often `paintComponent` is called you will likely have problems. You should instead only have `paintComponent` ask about the current state of some object and paint accordingly.

Depepending on your exact circumstances the 5 numbers should be provided in one of the following ways

- Passed to the constructor of BarGraph
- Requested from the user in the constructor of BarGraph (not my favourite, but would work)
- Passed to a method of BarGraph
- Be in some other object that is passed to BarGraph.

They absolutely should not be requested from the user inside the `paintComponent`, this means that every time a redraw is nessissary (e.g. moving, re-sizing, changing focus, being hidden by other frames etc) the numbers will be re-requested from the user.

You are also likely to want to start your `paintComponent` method with `super.paintComponent(g)` but that [will again be situation dependant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446768/2187042)