# Java, how to get into the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm a beginner in Java. My code:

```
public PlanetSimulator() throws InterruptedException {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(64, 35, 840, 600);
    Draw view = new Draw();
    panel.add(view);
```

Drawing in panel Sun and Stars and Black Background.

How can I say Java "Hey you see that panel? Draw there another thing"
But I'm saying in to Java not from the PlanetSimulator, but main function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PlanetSimulator frame = new PlanetSimulator();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                //DrawPlanetOne DrawPlanetOne = new DrawPlanetOne()
                //PlanetSimulator.panel.add(DrawPlanetOne)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work. Yes I known that I'm amateur.
Rysowanie / Draw class
http://pastebin.com/RkcTBxrN

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what your Draw.java does because i don't see you overriding paintComponent in your code. such as here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446396/concerns-about-the-function-of-jpanel-paintcomponent . Also you need a JFrame for the window. JFrame contains a JPanel which you draw on.

Comment: Sry, http://pastebin.com/RkcTBxrN My Rysowanie (draw) class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, this will be a simulation. And if you  like to simulate something with 30FPS, it will be hard with a Panel. You could use a library like [processing](http://www.processing.org) to animate your planets and stuff. It's a lot easier as using a JPane. But you could call the [repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392722/how-to-repaint-a-jpanel-after-have-drawn-on-it) method?