# Java-Image does not draw to screen while using a very small code

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I did a small test according to a problem in another program I am writing.
I need to draw an image to the screen, but it does not work.
However, I am able to draw rectangles to the screen, I do not understand

Code:

Main class:

```
package test;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final static int WW = 800;
    final static int WH = 600;
    public Main(){
        setSize(WW,WH);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Space Game");
        add(new testClass());
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

testClass class:

```
package test;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class testClass extends JPanel{
    private Image image;
    public testClass(){
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("spaceship.png");
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(50,50,50,50);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

Please help and explain why it does not work.
Sorry for bad English, any help is appreaciated :)
*I am sorry if my question is newbie, I am new in programming...

Comment: Where is spaceship.png stored?

Comment: In my java project map(im using eclipse)

Comment: Under `src` or immediately under the project?

Comment: In the folder with the name of my project, so not in src folder(do i have to move it in there?)

Comment: Okay, that should be fine. `drawImage` returns a boolean, what is the value of that boolean? From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)): "false if the image pixels are still changing; true otherwise."

Comment: How to see if it is true or false?

Comment: @HugoCornel You can print it out on the console

Comment: It prints true, but what do I have to do now to let is display to the screen?

Comment: Call super.paintComponent before you do any custom painting. Pass this as the ImageObserver to drawImage

Comment: To MadProgrammer: Why do I have to do that? It already works now

Comment: @HugoCornel, MadProgrammer is right, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5446768/3371872)'s "super.paintComponent" section for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one major error in your code:
`ImageIcon image` has method scope, while `Image image` has class scope. So the image you are trying to paint in `paintComponent` is not the same image that you've loaded in the constructor.

Fixing that won't be enough to make it work though. What I would recommend doing is the following. Use an `Image`. Then, in the constructor, assign it using `image = ImageIO.read(new File("spaceship.png"));`